# C# update a db entry with DBNull.value seems to error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Alright, maybe I am going around this wrong. We shall see.

So there is some data I am checking. This data is going to be type Int32. More or less, if the item wasn't one of my flags, I wanted to set it as `DBNull.value`, I believe.

The thing I am trying to determine is that the column is nullable, so if I don't enter anything into it, it shall be set to null.

Here is my program logic:

```
int content = 5;  //set for sake of program;
int test;
if( content == 5){
  test = content;
}else{
  //i want test to be labeled as DBNULL.
  //didnt know if i could redefine here to be like:
  //      free(test); DBNull test = new DBNull;
}
//my companys db command
CommandFactory cmd = new CommandFactory();
cmd.commandText = "insert into TABLE ( value ) values ( @a )";
cmd.addInputParameters("@a", test, DBType.Int32);
...
```

In this case, how would is et it to dbnull? be like:

```
if(test != -1){
    cmd.addInputParameters("@a", test, DBType.Int32);
}
//no param would be entered for @a, maybe forcing it to be null?
```

**In the definition of the table, value is nullable, so you wouldn't need to worry about that.**

*While the correct answer is posted, it is not the one I ended up using as my coworkers didn't want me to do "magic" with ??, so they had me do:*

```
int? temp;
if(temp.HasValue){
    cmd.addInputParameters("@a", temp, DBType.Int32);
}else{
    cmd.addInputParameters("@a", DBNull.Value, DBType.Int32);
}
```

Comment: I suggest learing LINQ to Entities unless you have a very good reason going about this the primitive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
int? test = content
...
cmd.addInputParameters("@a", (object)test ?? DbNull.Value, DBType.Int32);
```

Comment: i forgot about that. That looks like it could be a great idea.  Im going to test it in a bit.  That looks like it should work..

Comment: Seems that when i try to do that, it will give an error saying: **Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'**

Comment: Have amended. The ?? operator wants the things on both sides to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really hard to understand, but I think what you're saying is that you want to have a possible nullable integer. Simply declare test to be a nullable int instead of a regular int. So:

`int? test = null;`

Comment: when i was doing this, and doing    test ?? DBNull.Value, i was getting an error saying:  **Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to insert a nullable integer in db. I have made int a nullable datatype and for this it is compulsory that 'test' column in db should be nullable.

```
        int content = 5;  //set for sake of program;
        int? test = null;
        if (content == 5)
        {
            test = content;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into TABLE (columnNameforTest) values ( @test)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", test);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstring");
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```